# Overful \hbox en linea de \begin{document} en Beamer

Tags: latex

Estoy preparando una presentación con Overleaf y, con solamente la primera diapositiva ya he obtenido este error

> Overfull \hbox (108.58081pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 76--76  ‪main.tex, 76‬
> Overfull \hbox (110.00397pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active

Me extraña que la línea 76 es la de \begin{document} Os dejo el código a ver si me pudierais echar un cable. He visto por ahí que el error se puede deber al paquete AtBeginSection, pero no he encontrado cómo solucionarlo. Un saludo y muchas gracias. A continuación el código:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,xcdraw,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace} % Definir interlineado
\setstretch{1.1} % Interlineado
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Imprescindible texto
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Idem
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Texto en castellano
\usepackage{array} % Opciones extras para tablas sobre dimensiones
\usepackage{multicol,multirow} % Unir filas y columnas en tablas
\usepackage{verbatim} % Meter codigo en entorno verbatim
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,mathtools,amssymb,amstext,amsfonts,fixmath} % Todo lo de mates
\usepackage{cancel} % Para tachar elementos en ecuaciones que se cancelan
\usepackage{enumitem} % Fancy enumerate (cambiar iteradores)
\usepackage{comment} % Para añadir comentarios multilinea
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{url} % Meter links
\usepackage{theoremref} % \thlabel{label entorno theorem} \thref{label} Tª # \thnameref{label} Nombre Tª 
\usepackage{booktabs} % Modificar estilo tablas para que queden guapas
\usepackage{graphicx} % Includegraphics avanzado
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\graphicspath{{images/}} % Carpeta donde estan las imagenes
\usepackage{anysize} % Modificar márgenes
\usepackage{float} % Para poder usar [H] en figuras y se pongan justo donde quieres
\usepackage{hyperref} % Para las referencias cruzadas
\usepackage{caption} % Meter caption
\usepackage{subcaption} % Contiene a subfig y sirve para meter mas de una figura en entorno figure
\usepackage{wrapfig}% Para incorporar figuras que se mezclan con texto
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\util}{\widetilde{u}}
\renewcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\wI}{\widetilde{\mathcal{I}}}
\renewcommand{\H}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\usepackage{url}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5cm,text margin right=0.5cm} 
\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}
%\textbackslash
\newcommand{\celda}[1]{
    \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
        \vspace{5mm}
        #1
        \vspace{5mm}
    \end{minipage}
}
\title{Exposición ejercicios EDP}
\author{ Nuria Gallego Ariño }
\date{\today}
\institute{ Universidad de Valencia. Facultad de Ciencias Matemáticas. }
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.0775]{Logo uv.jpg}}
\institute{ Universidad de Valencia. Facultad de Ciencias Matemáticas. }
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Contenido}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Ejercicios sorteados}
\begin{frame}{Ejercicio 5 Práctica 5}
Claim: $\forall \Omega \subset \R^2$ $u\in C^2(\Omega) $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te da no es un error, es un warning. Los warnings se dan cuando LaTeX considera que tienes que mirar una parte de tu código porque algo no encaja del todo.

En tu caso, el warning es un `overfull box`. Se da cuando el contenido de una *caja* es demasiado grande y no puede ajustarse al espacio que tiene (en tu caso es demasiado ancho, por eso es `\hbox`, en vertical es `\vbox`). El valor que te da entre paréntesis es la cantidad de espacio o de puntos que excede del espacio disponible. Puedes encontrar más información del warning [aquí.](https://es.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Understanding_underfull_and_overfull_box_warnings#Overfull_and_underfull_boxes)

En tu código, el warning proviene de la siguiente línea

```
\institute{ Universidad de Valencia. Facultad de Ciencias Matemáticas. }
```

Ese texto no entra en la base de cada diapositiva y LaTeX te advierte de ello.